# What's a positive term to describe small eyes?

Tags: single-word-requests

You never hear someone saying "*beautiful **small** eyes*", "*nice **beady** eyes*" or "*cute **squinty** eyes*" (except, you do hear, "*beautiful **large** eyes*").

As far as I know, all the synonyms for small-shaped eyes seem to have a negative connotation to them.

Now, is there a rather positive or optimistic word for small eyes or eyes that are small in shape?

Comment: The negative connotations are because small eyes are traditionally considered a negative trait. I doubt there are any positively loaded words for small eyes, just like there are no positive words (that I know of) for greasy hair, wrinkly skin, crooked noses, yellow teeth, wiry hair, or wonky legs.

Comment: I think the best you could do would be to find an ethnic group or country where that type of eye shape is common, and make reference to that, like "You have lovely Finnish-looking eyes" or something along those lines. (note - I picked "Finnish" because they often have some Inuit/Asian genetic heritage)

Comment: As eyes are considered the window to the soul, bigger is universally better. Since the days of Cleopatra, eyeliner makes eyes look bigger and outlines their importance to the face. Men from Morocco to Afghanistan used it.

Comment: I had always thought 'beady eyes' were specifically for the soulless, empty headed eyes of some birds, with no size connotation. Does anybody else find this? All the on-line dictionaries do not say this; they all say small and with bad intent. (so I'm probably wrong, I'm just checking)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What happened to the colour of someone's eyes? It doesn't matter what size their eyes are, it's what they express that counts. E. Groeg,  ignore the size, look deep into her eyes and sigh... and tell her that her eyes shine like stars, thousands of light years away.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Eye colour seems to be much less unanimously judged. Sure, you've got baby blues as an inherently positive marker of blue eyes, but apart from very rare and to some extent unnatural ones like yellow or red, I can't think of any eye colour that isn't also associated with positive things.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think it will partially depend on how you want to use the term. Can you include an example sentence, showing where it would go? This will help us to understand the exact nuance you want (romantic? manly? formal/informal?) and is also technically required for single-word-requests.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - actually, there are myriad ways to describe those bodily attributes in positive ways...if you do a little paradigm shift on what is considered attractive.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Of course, but that is true of everything. Disfigurement, maiming, oozing wounds, murder—those are all fairly unilaterally considered negative things, but they can all be described positively. My point was that, to my knowledge, there are no set phrases or common collocations that do so, whereas there are plenty that describe them negatively.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - point taken, but I draw the line on oozing wounds. :-p

Comment: @KristinaLopez Personally I'd prefer not to get close enough to oozing wounds to draw anything on them, but to each their own!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet How particularly is it a negative trait (unless if you want to be gender-specific)? Because you'd rarely find women falling for guys like Elijah Wood, who possess large blue eyes. Instead you'd see them being allured by guys like Channing Tatum and Brad Pitt with squinty, smaller eyes.

Comment: @YosefBaskin You're talking about male attractiveness standards from 2000 years ago. Do we see large-eyed, mascara-wearing men in the media today being displayed as sex symbols, or even in the Middle East? I don't think so. Say, I wrote "sexy eyes men" on Google and noticed how the majority of these standard "good-looking" guys lacked large eyes: https://www.google.com.au/search?biw=1360&bih=648&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=sexy+eyes+men&oq=sexy+eyes+men&gs_l=psy-ab.3...19094.21624.0.21835.18.11.0.0.0.0.328.1246.2-4j1.5.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..13.4.917...0j0i67k1.48HLT0CBdpI#imgrc=_

Comment: @E.Groeg Brad Pitt and Channing Tatum both have perfectly normal-sized eyes, and there are plenty of people who think Elijah Wood and his eyes are gorgeous too. Besides, I said small eyes are _perceived_ as a negative trait; that is, the notion of ‘(unusually) small eyes’ is something that most people have negative connotations to. The same people may not even notice below-average-sized eyes when they see them, just like they probably wouldn't notice if someone had greasy hair or a crooked nose, unless it is very pronounced. We frequently don't do as we say and think we do.

Comment: Also note that ‘squinty eyes’ does not mean small eyes. Eyes that are wide but narrow are often called almond-shaped and are rarely viewed unfavourable; think bedroom eyes. Small, beady eyes are ones where the entire socket and eye is smaller, both horizontally and vertically—especially vertically. [This](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-BD-zPSXUsmw/T0F_4SspxKI/AAAAAAAABiA/yT72KUz21zc/s1600/colmmeaney-startrek1.jpg) is small, beady eyes (but again, most people would probably not even notice unless they were thinking about it).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet To me, Pitt and Tatum have small, narrow eyes. This is an attractive trait for a male. Small shouldn't always mean creepily beady, unusually shaped and microscopic, just the same way large shouldn't mean bulgy and alien. There is positivity to both. Again, most sex symbols have narrow, "small-ish" eyes that are hooded or "half closed" - Ricky Martin, Clint Eastwood, Richard Gere, Adam Levine, Colin Farrel, etc. Elijah Wood is adored for his baby-face cuteness, not sexual attractiveness. :)

Answer (score 3):

Anything along the lines of elfin or miniature can be construed as positive, I suppose:

"Her perfectly heart-shaped pixie-like face was bejeweled with the most exquisitely formed emerald green eyes...small, like the rest of her, but sparkling with quick wit and wisdom."

And to be clear, shape would almond, oval, round, etc. The size would be small, doll-like, miniature, tiny, etc. - none of which are necessarily negative.

Comment: Elfin sounds beautiful and rather appropriate here: 

"If you describe someone as elfin, you think that they are attractive because they are small and have delicate features."

Source: Collins Dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Metaphor could be used to indicate smallness without saying so directly - e.g. "bright, lively, gimlet eyes that see everything" ... a gimlet is a tool for making small holes, so using this metaphor praises penetrating vision, and smallness comes along for the ride as a connotation.

Alternatively comparing them to gems "like two sparkling sapphires" (or emeralds, or diamonds or...) again smallness is a connotation since even valuable gems are generally small.

Comment: The [*gimlet eye*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gimlet-eye)?

Comment: But I like your notes in the direction of *sparkly* eyes.

Comment: @Lawrence "Piercing" vision is not negative, it's a complement though quite a specific one - Though if you are trying to get away with something you won't like the gimlet eye!   https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=O3A_WqpPSdkC&pg=PA398&dq=%22gimlet+eye%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbo7qahqLVAhVpI8AKHW-GAk8Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22gimlet%20eye%22&f=false

Comment: I'm not sure *gimlet eye* works as a compliment. Even as a complement (to *sharp* intellect, perhaps), it doesn't seem (to me) to come across positively.

Comment: What about "bedroom eyes"? Don't they indicate a person with smaller eyes?

Comment: No, "bedroom eyes" does not really have anything to do with size. It conveys flirtatiousness or sexual allure.

Answer (score 0):

"Petite eyes" has a neutral connotation that can be made positive with further supporting context.

Comment: "Petite" is more appropriate to describe a slender body. I mean, you can might as well use "slim eyes", "thin eyes" or "lean eyes". And they don't sound quite right. :)

Comment: haha Good point, "lean eyes" is definitely weird.

Comment: What about "hunter eyes"? They're usually narrow and squinty, and they're perceived as alluring.